# How to set tx_news (TYPO3) title in breadcrumb WITH link

Tags: typo3, typoscript, breadcrumbs, tx-news

I implemented tx_news title in breadcrumb always like shown here with typoscript: [How to set breadcrumb for tx_news TYPO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872462/how-to-set-breadcrumb-for-tx-news-typo3/38872732#38872732) and it works fine but for now i need to get an link on the news title which points to itself. This is needed for structurel data correctness (https://schema.org/). See structurel data testing tools on any news single view for that issue. I didn't get that to work and don't find any hints online beside the above one.
Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint. This did the job for me:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]      
lib.menu.breadcrumb.20 = COA
lib.menu.breadcrumb.20 {
  wrap = <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="active"> | <meta itemprop="position" content="2" /></li>
  10 = TEXT
  10.wrap = <a href="|" target="_top" itemprop="item">
  10.data = getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_URL
  20 = RECORDS
  20 {
    dontCheckPid = 1
    tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
    source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
    source.intval = 1
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.field = title
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    wrap = <span itemprop="name">|</span>
  }
  30 = TEXT
  30.value = </a>
}
[end]
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
lib.url = TEXT
lib.url.data = getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_URL
```